# Download stats for snap apps

Tags: snap

Does the snap store feature a publicly available download statistics (in the form of numbers, not the relative usage in different distros and countries) for each snap?

Stats can be seen for PPAs using tools like [ppa-stats](https://github.com/YokoZar/ppa-stats). It would be nice if something like this were available for snap store as well.

Comment: If you go to the snap store (eg. https://snapcraft.io/firefox for firefox), and scroll down you can see the users by distribution (log) in a graph; plus a map of the world showing where the concentration of the people are in the world. It's not complete, but it's a guide.

Comment: It does not show any numbers